# Pandas ошибка: KeyError: "None of [Index(['Binary'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

CSV файл таблица:

```
      Binary  16_bit
0          0       0
1          1       1
2         10       2
3         11       3
4        100       4
5        101       5
6        110       6
7        111       7
8       1000       8
9       1001       9
10      1010      10
11      1011      11
12      1100      12
13      1101      13
14      1110      14
15      1111      15
16     10000      16
17     10001      17
18     10010      18
19     10011      19
20     10100      20
21     10101      21
22     10110      22
23     10111      23
24     11000      24
25     11001      25
26     11010      26
27     11011      27
28     11100      28
29     11101      29
```

код:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv("D:/Dataset.csv", sep=',')
x = dataset['Binary']
y = dataset['16_bit']
print(x)
```

ошибка:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Binary'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: У вас исходный файл точно разделен запятыми? в противном случае при чтении файла вы получаете одну колонку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная ошибка говорит о том что в DataFrame'е `dataset` отсутствует столбец `Binary`.

Посмотреть все столбцы можно так:

```
print(dataset.columns.tolist())
```

Если приведенный в вопросе пример данных на самом деле является вашим CSV, то прочитать его можно так:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)
```